# Bash shell decimal test

Tags: bash, floating-point

My shell is bash and I have three variables
x=5; y=7; z=7.5

I am trying to use the below statement to test the equality of variables $y and $z as shown below

Command: `test $z -eq $y; echo $?`

But, it shows the following error and I am not able to resolve it.

> -bash: test: 7.2: integer expression expected
>
> 2

**Note**: when I apply the same test command on integers $x and $y, they work fine.

Comment: i am not sure how to apply "bc in this case

Comment: Can't you use string comparison "=" for your use case? Float comparison for equality is usually not very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `==` operator of `bc`.

```
test "$(echo $x == $z |bc)" -eq 1
```

> expr1 == expr2
>   The result is 1 if expr1 is equal to expr2.

-- from man bc(1)